# Parallelizing sed gives different output

Tags: shell, sed, quoting, gnu-parallel

Trying to parallelize a sed operation however, while the parallel version works, it gives back a wrong output.

The sed operation that I would like to parallelize (works)

```
sed 's/\s.*$// ; s/\(.*\)/\L\1/' < oldfile.txt > newfile.txt
```

My Parallel version of the above sed operation (Does not work correctly for some reason):

```
parallel -a oldfile.txt -k --block $BYTES --pipe-part "sed 's/\s.*$// ; s/\(.*\)/\L\1/'" > newfile.txt
```

Comment: Looks like you're trying to extract the fist column/field and lowercase it; keep in mind regex is expensive (read _slow_) so `s/\s.*$//` will be much slower than e.g. `cut -f1` and `s/\(.*\)/\L\1/'` will be much slower than e.g. `tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]'`... Optimization more often than not means using the right tools for the job.

Comment: @don_crissti how is tr not using regex? isn't [:upper:] a regex class?

Comment: It' a character class not a regex.

Comment: @don_crissti I got a dramatic boost by replacing it with tr and cut... Thanks for the tip... Any chance that I could use tr and cut in one file scan? That would lower the time even further I guess.. I mean the way it is now, tr and cut are scanning the file one time each... It would be nice if there was a solution that practically does whatever tr and cut does (extract the fist column/field and lowercase it), and then move to the next line ect.. (one scan) Is there any way to approach this?

Comment: You don't do one line at a time, you just run `cut -f1 infile | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]'` that is extract the 1st column from the entire file and then lowercase the result via `tr` there is no further optimization as both `cut` and `tr` are optimized for their jobs and will be hundreds of times faster than `sed`; this also assumes the columns are tab-separated (not a mix of spaces/tabs) otherwise you'll have to `tr` (space) (tab) first  but that's also very very fast...

Comment: @don_crissti you just said "extract the 1st column from the entire file and then lowercase the result via tr"  so the "extract the 1st column" is the first scan/pass the "lowercase the result via tr" is the second, do you agree? I am thinking about a way to "extract first line and then lowercase the result via tr" * number_of_lines . Do you see what I mean ? There is no question that those operations are extremly fast , I am just asking out of curiosity

Comment: Come to think... to do it in a single pass you'd use `awk '{print tolower($1)}' infile`

Comment: @don_crissti do you think using awk could potentially be faster?

Comment: It should be faster than `sed`. I don't know if it can beat the `cut | tr` combination (I kinda doubt that...)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58763/discussion-between-hashwizard-and-don-crissti).

Answer (score 5):

This is usually due to double quoting.

Quoting is annoying, so try instead using a shell function:

```
mysed() {
    sed 's/\s.*$// ; s/\(.*\)/\L\1/'
}
export -f mysed

parallel -a oldfile.txt -k --block -1 --pipe-part mysed > newfile.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

GNU parallel invokes the command that you specify through a shell. This is occasionally convenient, but often a pain, as you've discovered, because of the quoting issues and the dependency on the `SHELL` environment variable. (Ole and I have already had words about that.)

You have to tell parallel that what you're passing is *an executable with arguments*, rather than the default behavior which assumes that the arguments are *a command to be executed by the program named by the `SHELL` environment variable, arbitrarily split into pieces that are joined together with a space in between*. There's no such option; the closest thing is to tell parallel to quote the command so that the shell will end up running the correct command.

```
parallel -a oldfile.txt -k --block $BYTES --pipe-part -q sed 's/\s.*$// ; s/\(.*\)/\L\1/' > newfile.txt
```